# Xamarin project always entering NETSTANDARD2_0 directive in my library

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth, directive

I am writing a Bluetooth LE plugin for Xamarin.

The target platforms of the library are netstandard2.0, MonoAndroid9.0 and Xamarin.iOS10.

The library is being referenced from the shared Xamarin project which is netstandard2.0.

Various parts of the code are segmented by preprocessor directives validating the target platform.

But when executing from the Android project, the execution always enters the NETSTANDARD2_0 directive and not the other one.

Where can be the problem?

Comment: Can you please share the code from the project including the NETSTANDARD2_0 directive?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! As a new contributor you may find it useful to have a look at [ask].